# Why is Elasticsearch with Wildcard Query always 1.0?

Tags: elasticsearch

When i do a search in Elasticsearch with a Wildcard-Query (Wildcard at the End) the score results for all hits in 1.0.
Is this by design? Can I change this behavior somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch is basically saying that all results are equally relevant, as you've provided an unqualified search (a wildcard, equivalent to a `match_all`).  As soon as you add some additional context through the various *types* of queries, you will notice changes in the scoring.

Depending on your ultimate goal, you may want to look into the `Function Score` query - reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

The first example provided would give you essentially random scores for all documents in your cluster:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "boost": "5",
            "random_score": {}, 
            "boost_mode":"multiply"
        }
    }
}
```